# Redshift Python API to query list of SQL procedures

Tags: python, sql, amazon-redshift

I am developing an app to parse an SQL query to be executed on redshift database. Is there any api provided which either takes a string and returns whether it is a supported SQL function in redshift, or returns a list of all supported redshift SQL functions? (I did find a reference to all the available SQL functions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_SQL_functions.html). I was wondering if there was a python API which would return the same result.) Connecting to redshift and running the appropriate query to get this info is an option, but not a feasible one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Reality**

I have been developing an ORM for some time now, and there's a lot of the JDBC API offers to you in terms of metadata information about the database. It actually offers you the list of functions for numeric, varchar and dates values.

Unfortunately, the JDBC driver (and I imagine other drivers too) most of the time do not implement such part of the specification, and the call ends up returning an empty list.

In other cases, it actually returns a list of functions but it's blatantly outdated. Maybe the method was implemented 10 years ago, and no one updated it in any recent version of the driver or the database.

I would advise against relying on any database metadata that goes beyond the minimal set of operations. Yes, unfortunately that is my experience with 10 main stream databases so far, and I guess minor databases may be worse in this respect.

**A Workaround**

Now, if you really need to query that information at runtime, you can still assemble a SQL statement that uses the *candidate* function, run it, and see if it runs or crashes. Not the ideal option, but I guess this will clearly tell you if it's implemented or not. Running it for hundreds of functions should take no time.

Comment: Sounds like a fair hack. Pretty weird that AWS doesn't provided a common API which is updated every time a function is added.